# using d3 brush can't change the d3.time scale's domain value

Tags: d3.js

I have built a d3 js code make a brush on the time axis line with the following d3.js code, what I want to do to change the d3.time.scale()'s domain as I drag the brush

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
   <head>
        <title>Visualization of Room</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body >

        <div id="abc" > </div>  
    </body>

    <script>

    var width = 1700,
        height = 700,
        padding = 100;

    // create an svg container
    var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

    var startHour = 9, endHour = 18, startTimeline = 100, endTimeline = 1200;

    var now = new Date(), 
    mindate = new Date( now.getFullYear (),now.getMonth(),now.getDate(),startHour),
    maxdate = new Date( now.getFullYear (),now.getMonth(),now.getDate(),endHour);
    var xScale = d3.time.scale().domain([mindate, maxdate]).range([startTimeline, endTimeline]);    

    var time_control, brush;
    function showTimeControl(){

        time_control = vis.append('g').attr('class','time_control'); 
        /*****************  brush  ************************/

        brush = d3.svg.brush().x(xScale).extent([mindate,maxdate])
                      .on("brush", onbrushmove)

        time_control.append("g").attr("class", "brush").call(brush)
                                 .selectAll("rect")                              
                                 .attr("y", 6)
                                 .attr("height",  50);  


    }
        function onbrushmove(){
            var s = brush.extent();
            //xScale.domain( s);
            console.log('on brush move',brush.empty(), s[0],s[1]);  
            document.getElementById('abc').innerHTML = s[0]+ "     "+s[1];          
        }  
    showTimeControl();


</script>

</html>
```

However the problem comes when I dragged the brush, the brush will only show the same value / date if the line `xScale.domain( s);` is used

```
function onbrushmove(){
    var s = brush.extent();
    xScale.domain( s);
    console.log('on brush move',brush.empty(), s[0],s[1]);          
}
```

if the line `xScale.domain( s);` is not used, the console will output the changing values normally

you can check http://jsfiddle.net/UmpF5/, in the jsfiddle demo, it works in the beginning, but when you drag more, it will stop working

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. The expected behaviour is that when you drag the brush, the selection changes to what the brush covers. Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: what I want to do is to change the d3.time.scale()'s domain as I drag the brush, but it won't work, you can see the demo on http://jsfiddle.net/UmpF5/

Comment: actually I want to say, in the jsfiddle demo, it works in the begining, but when you drag more, it will stop working

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't seem to do anything at all for me. You may want to check whether the brush is empty before setting it as domain.

Comment: the brush is not empty always, I have updated the jsfiddle again

Comment: My point is that you shouldn't set the `xScale` domain to an empty one, see e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367). And your jsfiddle still doesn't seem to do anything.